# Excel VBA SQL Statement with Contains

Tags: sql, excel, vba, contains

I have a table in Excel which I want to use to get some measures via SQL.

This is the first part of my code, which works fine:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MySQL()

    Dim cn As Object, rs As Object, output As String, sql As String

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
        .Open
    End With
```

Now I can get the amount of entries with a specific condition like:

```
sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM [Data$] WHERE [Type] = ""myType"" and [Status] = ""myStatus"""
Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)
MsgBox (rs(0))
```

Now I would like to use a **CONTAINS** condition, but this does not work:

```
sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM [Data$] WHERE CONTAINS([Type], ""T"")"
Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)
MsgBox (rs(0))
```

Comment: Did you try using LIKE ?

Comment: This returns me a 0 but at least no error:
sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM [Data$] WHERE [Type] LIKE ""*T*"""

Do I still have a Syntax issue?

Comment: You need wildcard(s) presumably e.g. `%T%`

Comment: wildcard=% was the hint I needed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Contains` is a non-standard SQL function that is available in SQL Server (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). It is used to perform fuzzy searches of all kinds.

`Contains` is not available when you query other data sources (Excel, Access, Oracle...).

If you just look for a substring, you can use the `like`-operator and use `%` as wildcard, eg

```
sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM [Data$] WHERE [Type] like '%T%' "
```

`'%T%'` will find anything containing the letter T
`'T%'` will find anything starting with the letter T
`'%T'` will find anything ending with the letter T
(this is, of course, not limited to a single character, you can use `'%overflow%'` if you want).

Note that different database systems have different rules for case sensitivity. Querying Excel is case insensitive, so `like %t%` and `like %T%` return the same result. This is different on other databases.

You should, btw, make it a habit to use single quotes for constant text within an SQL statement. Double quotes work in Excel but are not SQL standard and will fail in most databases.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question regarding CONTAINS.
It works now perfectly with LIKE